# VSCode `down` key not detected

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to switch between opened integrated terminals with the following:

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+up",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+down",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNext",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  },
```

The `ctrl+up` works as expected but VSCode does not respond to `ctrl+down`.

I looked at the keyboard trouble shooting but can't find any actionable info there

```
# ctrl+up
[2022-09-16 10:23:11.544] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
[2022-09-16 10:23:11.545] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
[2022-09-16 10:23:11.545] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
[2022-09-16 10:23:11.546] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
[2022-09-16 10:23:11.546] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
[2022-09-16 10:23:11.615] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
[2022-09-16 10:23:11.615] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving ctrl+[ArrowUp]
[2022-09-16 10:23:11.616] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 1 keybinding entries, matched workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious, when: terminalFocus, source: user.
[2022-09-16 10:23:11.617] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ArrowUp, keyCode: 38, key: ArrowUp
[2022-09-16 10:23:11.617] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ArrowUp, keyCode: 16 ('UpArrow')
[2022-09-16 10:23:11.618] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving ctrl+[ArrowUp]
[2022-09-16 10:23:11.620] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 1 keybinding entries, matched workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious, when: terminalFocus, source: user.
[2022-09-16 10:23:11.621] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: + Invoking command workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious.
[2022-09-16 10:23:11.700] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
[2022-09-16 10:23:11.700] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Resolving ctrl+[ArrowUp]
[2022-09-16 10:23:11.701] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ From 1 keybinding entries, matched workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious, when: terminalFocus, source: user.
[2022-09-16 10:23:11.809] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
[2022-09-16 10:23:11.809] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
[2022-09-16 10:23:11.810] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: + Ignoring single modifier ctrl due to it being pressed together with other keys.


# ctrl+down

[2022-09-16 10:23:41.610] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
[2022-09-16 10:23:41.611] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
[2022-09-16 10:23:41.612] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
[2022-09-16 10:23:41.612] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
[2022-09-16 10:23:41.612] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
[2022-09-16 10:23:42.289] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
[2022-09-16 10:23:42.289] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
[2022-09-16 10:23:42.290] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: + Storing single modifier for possible chord ctrl.
[2022-09-16 10:23:42.594] [renderer10] [info] [KeybindingService]: + Clearing single modifier due to 300ms elapsed.
```

Note: I have disabled the system shortcut `ctrl+down` that is assigned to "Show Application Windows" by default